# ¿Cómo solucionar este error del webconfig?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Se me ha presentado el siguiente mensaje de error y no comprendo porque sucede este tipo de error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi configuración en el  webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Acceso/Index" timeout="2000" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: estas corriendo en remoto la app?

Comment: Eh, no. Te está diciendo "hubo un error, pero no te voy a decir nada sobre el error porque tienes configurado para que no se vean detalles del error desde terminales remotas. Sólo te voy a decir CUÁL es el error si abres esta página desde un navegador en el servidor". Una de dos, o vas y abres esa página en un navegador en el servidor, o **temporalmente** cambias la configuración como te lo indica para que muestre los errores a clientes remotos (o miras algún log para saber cuál fue el error)

Comment: Veo que marcastes una respuesta, podrias reponder a tu propia pregunta y colocar la solucion? El objetivo del sitio es ayudarte y ayudar a los demas miembros de la comunidad, porque tal vez tengan un problema parecido

Comment: Mi código solucionó tu error de no poder visualizarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres que te muestre el verdadero error puedes poner en tu Web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        Para examinar el directorio raíz de la aplicación web durante la depuración, establezca el valor siguiente en true.
        Establézcalo en false antes de la implementación para evitar revelar información sobre la carpeta de aplicación web.
      -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
          <remove fileExtension="." />
          <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Asi podrás ver lo que realmente te está causando la excepción.

Comment: Creo que seria mas una sugerencia que una respuesta, por otro lado el OP lo marco como respuesta en ese caso se deduce que el soluciono el problema pero ¿Cual era el error?

Comment: Estaba ejecutando la aplicación web  cuando se estaba actualizado la fuente publicada es por ello el mensaje.

Comment: @JuanRivera el error era que no mostraba el error, o por lo menos las veces que yo he tenido algo similar se solucionaba con esto.