# ¿Error en las variables de sesión tiene nulo?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, linq

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Se me ha presentado el siguiente error en mis variables de sesión para obtener el nombre del usuario, perfil, etc.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi duda es que cuando termina el tiempo de sesión las variables se vuelven nulos y si es así como puedo solucionar este problema ya que uso variables de sessión para obtener ciertos datos del usuario.

```
<a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                    @{
                        Usuario usuario = (Usuario)Session["objUsuario"];
                        if (usuario != null)
                        {
                            <span class="username username-hide-on-mobile" id="nom_usu_ses">
                                @usuario.Nombre.ToString()
                            </span>

                        }

                        <input type="hidden" name="Ids" id="Ids" value="@usuario.Id" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="idUsuario" id="idUsuario" value="@usuario.CodUsuario.ToString().Trim()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="correoHidden" id="correoHidden" value="@usuario.CorreoResponsable.ToString().Trim()" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="perfilHidden" id="perfilHidden" value="@usuario.CodPerfil.ToString().Trim()" />

                    }
                    <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
                </a>
```

Del error mostrado deduzco que puede ser ese el problema y que solución podría darle.

Mi configuración webconfig

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Acceso/Index" timeout="2000" />
    </authentication>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: Es referente a esta pregunta? https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/423836/c%c3%b3mo-solucionar-este-error-del-webconfig Si es asi, es mejor editar la otra y poner esos detalles

Comment: No este era un problema cuando habia publicado mi codigo en la web, en cambio este me genera un error en mis variables de sesión.

Comment: Lo que entiendo que te sucede, es que estas ejecutando los metodos `ToString()` y `Trim()` sobre un valor null, entonces rompe tu aplicacion. Lo podrias solucionar de esta forma. `@usuario.CorreoResponsable?.ToString().Trim()` Colocando el ? antes de ejecutar el metodo, si es null no lo ejecuta y no te rompe

Comment: Recuerda que sesión y autenticación no son lo mismo. Si en el login, en el que se autentica, le das esos valores a la sesión; cuando la sesión caduque esos valores desaparecen (pasan a ser null). El usuario puede seguir autenticado y al acceder a tu aplicación crearsele una sesión nueva sin pasar por el login. Por lo que no se rellenan esos campos y te daría ese error. Lo normal es que el usuario se obtenga a partir del ticket de autenticación y no de la sesión. ¿Será este tu caso?